# Ionic - Inline datetime picker

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing a mobile app and I need to use the [datetime component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) as inline, **not** as popup (regular usage) but documentation hasn't any instrument to do it, anyone know a similar component or a correct way to print as inline?

Mockup:

[image: mockup]

Comment: Cami Rodriguez, Have you done this inline picker?